# How can I add colour to a specific string using python curses?

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

For Example, I have string `"Colour selected is red"` How do I make only the word "red" red?

This is what I'm using to try and achieve this.

```
import curses

curses.start_color()
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
win = curses.newwin(5 + window_height, window_width, 2, 4)

win.addstr(position + 2, 5, "Colour selected is " + "Red", curses.color_pair(1))
```

it's part of a bigger project so some info might be missing. But it does not work.

Comment: What code have you tried?  Can you give us an excerpt?

Comment: Ok snippet added

Comment: I tried changing the color to red using the termcolor python library but this is what happens: `^[[31mred^[[0m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
import curses

curses.initscr();

window_height = curses.LINES - 2
window_width = curses.COLS - 2
position = 3

curses.start_color()
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
win = curses.newwin(5 + window_height, window_width, 2, 4)

win.addstr(position + 2, 5, "Colour selected is " + "Red", curses.color_pair(1))

win.getch()
```

If you had reduced the problem to a simple, complete program, you would probably see the problem in your original program.

Following up on comment: in curses, the `addstr` function applies the attribute (including color) to the whole *string* parameter.  If you want to have different parts of the string with different attributes, you will have to make separate calls to `addstr`, one for each attribute as applied to parts of the original string.  Something like this:

```
win.addstr(position + 2, 5, "Colour selected is ")
win.addstr("Red", curses.color_pair(1))
```

Comment: That's expected behavior: addstr has 3 optional parameters (the position pair and the attribute).  The *attribute* applies to the *string* parameter.  If you wanted 2 strings, you'll have to make 2 calls to addstr.